# php ftp connection timed out while working - reconnect? detect?

Tags: php, ftp, connection

Is it possible to detect if the ftp resource is disconnected or timed out?

A **sample** script

```
<?php
$connection = ftp_connect('127.0.0.1');
ftp_login($connection, '123', '456');
sleep(660); // proftpd has 600 as default no transfer timeout
ftp_chdir($connection, '/');
ftp_close($connection);
```

Then we got a **warning**

```
Warning:
ftp_chdir():
    No transfer timeout (600 seconds):
        closing control connection in line 5
```

Is it possible to check if disconnected or timed out?

```
if(!$connection)
```

doesnt work because the resource exists...
But the resource is timed out :/

Comment: Since to check the connection state you need to try to comminicate with a server, I would suggest to `ftp_exec($connection, 'NOOP')`. It’s kinda “ping” analogue.

Comment: `Warning: ftp_exec(): 'SITE EXEC' not understood`

Comment: Oh, sorry, mistyped: `ftp_raw($connection, 'NOOP')` of course.

Comment: Ah great ^^ That would work. But what if i use the sleep(601)? Then i cant send noop each second while sleep :D

Comment: You seemed to want check if the connection is alive, didn’t you?

Comment: Yes i want to check if the connection is alive :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this something like this

```
if(is_array(ftp_nlist($connection, "."))){
    echo "Connected";
}
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php